# s3cmd restore recursive not working right

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd, amazon-glacier

I am running the following command to restore the data from Amazon S3 to the web server.
`s3cmd restore --recursive s3://my-bucket/Weekly-Sunday/dbexports/`
and getting this error:

`Restore is not allowed, as object's storage class is not GLACIER`
On the other hand when I tried --dry-run it didn't show problems.

I am using amazon s3, but not GLACIER and this command to sync:

`s3cmd sync LOCAL_DIR s3://my-bucket/Weekly-Sunday/dbexports/` to move data to Amazon s3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was very simple. The restore option is meant only for **Glacier** storage: (http://s3tools.org/usage)
This little command with inverted parameters would do the job.

`s3cmd sync s3://my-bucket/Weekly-Sunday/dbexports/ LOCAL_DIR`